# How to calculate correlation coefficient if the data set is not provided?

Tags: probability

> In a relay race, teams of $4$ people are able to break up the $10$-mile course however they like.  On your team, the average speed each person can run is $0.15$ miles per minute with an SD of $0.10$ miles per minute.  The average amount of time each person took to run their part was $20$ minutes with an SD of $15$ minutes.  Note that each person ran a different distance.  What is the correlation between the speed of a person and how much time they ran in the race?

In this problem, since the data set is not provided how can we compute the correlation?

I looked up the formula to calculate correlation, and an alternative way to calculate is through $r=\frac {Cov(X,Y)}{SDx\cdot SDy}$ Is calculating Covariance of $(X,Y)$ possible in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we say $X$ is the speed of each racer then we have four observations for $X$ - let's call these $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \}$. And if we say $Y$ is the time that each racer ran for we also have four observations for $Y$ - let's call these $\{y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4 \}$.

The formula for covariance is

$\text{Cov} (X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$

You are given the expected values (the averages) of $X$ and $Y$. And you can calculate $E[XY]$ as follows:

$E[XY] = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i y_i = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=1}^4 d_i$

where $d_i$ is the distance run by the $i$th racer (since speed times time = distance). But $\sum_{i=1}^4 d_i$ is the total distance of the race  which is 10 miles. So

$E[XY] = 2.5 \text{ miles}$

Now you have all the values you need to calculate $\text{Cor}(X,Y)$.

Comment: It never even occurred to me to think of E[XY] as distance! Thank you!